# How do I add a new column to a Spark dataframe for every row that exists?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a comparison matrix using a Spark dataframe, and am starting by creating a single column dataframe with one row per value:

```
val df = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toDF
```

From here, what I need to do is create a new column for each row, and insert (for now), a random number in each space, like this:

```
  Item   1   2   3   4   5  
 ------ --- --- --- --- --- 
     1   0   7   3   6   2  
     2   1   0   4   3   1  
     3   8   6   0   4   4  
     4   8   8   1   0   9  
     5   9   5   3   6   0
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: use `withColumn("newcolumnname", logic)`

Comment: @Giri thanks for your reply - If I iterate over the rows, adding a column each time, it returns a Unit object, which I cannot convert into a dataframe.

Comment: You should consider to use the `.pivot()` function after grouping by `Item` Column

Comment: @pheeleeppoo do you have an example at all?

Comment: If `DataFrame` is large enough to use Spark in the first place, the required output, won't be feasible for a number of reasons (planner overhead, local memory usage). If you really work with only few items @pheeleeppoo answer will work, otherwise you should rethink the design.

Comment: @user10938362 the dataframe will be roughly 800 rows and 800 columns

Answer (score -1):

Considering to transpose the input DataFrame called `df` using `.pivot()` function like the following:

```
val output = df.groupBy("item").pivot("item").agg((rand()*100).cast(DataTypes.IntegerType))
```

This will generate a new DataFrame with a random Integer value corrisponding to the row value (`null` otherwise).

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|item|1   |2   |3   |4   |5   |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |9   |null|null|null|null|
|3   |null|null|2   |null|null|
|5   |null|null|null|null|6   |
|4   |null|null|null|26  |null|
|2   |null|33  |null|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

If you don't want the `null` values you can consider to apply an UDF later.

Comment: Thank you for this - one final question, in the example you posted (and also when I do the same), the rows are in order `1 3 5 4 2`. Any way to sort these numerically?

Comment: Simply add `.sort("item")` after the `agg` function. Please accept the answer if it helps you.